# Tweeted in edit history?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed a few times that there is an entry in the revision history that the question was tweeted.  What is this all about? I haven't seen this on other StackExchange sites, but maybe I just haven't noticed it yet.

For a full list of questions tweeted you can go here: https://twitter.com/StackStats

[Here is an example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/173458/revisions) picked at random from the tweets on that feed.

Comment: Just about all the SE sites have their own twitter accounts.  I don't know anything about how they work

Comment: @Glen_b Interesting.  I guess I'm not very observant elsewhere.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183407/how-does-the-twitter-bot-work

Comment: e.g. see here: http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/275268/revisions which was tweeted to [StackEnglish](https://twitter.com/StackEnglish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted a friend on another SE chat who gave me [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183407/301021) and they also posted it above as a comment by an anonymous user.  Basically the accepted answer said that:

> "it looks like each [SE controlled Twitter] account is set up to automatically tweet a new status every 3 hours"

In analyzing the links sent out by the Twitter stream it strongly appears that this is the action of a bot and not the action of a user promoting content in an attempt to get an [<kbd>Announcer</kbd>](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer), [<kbd>Booster</kbd>](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster), or [<kbd>Publicist</kbd>](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) badge.  This is because links generated by the [<kbd>share</kbd>](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2721/89026) link follow a distinct format of:

`<base url>/<q|a>/<question id | answer id>/<user id>`

The links shared in the Twitter stream drop the user id section so any user trying to earn badges like this couldn't earn the badge.

---

It seems on Facebook this work is done [manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244189/avoid-sharing-bad-questions-at-facebook).